# Javascript IE error: unexpected call to method or property access

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, methods

I have the following code and it's working (as usual) in everything but IE. It's giving me an unexpected call to method or property access in Jquery and I have no idea how to debug it. I've been using the IE developer toolbar, which is useless for this error and just gives me a line no 12 (inside the jquery script).

Any help is v much appreciated:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.history.init(pageload);

    $('a[href=' + window.location.hash + ']').addClass('selected');

    $('a[rel=ajax]').click(function () {

        var hash = this.href;
        hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');
        $.history.load(hash);

        $('a[rel=ajax]').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('.loading').show();

        getPage();

        return false;
    });
});

function pageload(hash) {
    if (hash) getPage();
}

function getPage() {

    hash = document.location.hash;
    hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');
    var data = 'page=' + encodeURIComponent(hash);
    $.ajax({
        url: "index.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('.loading').hide();
            $('tbody').html(html);

        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Here is the history plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history

And here is the demo I have been following:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history

Still changing window.location back to document.location doesn't seem to make a difference

I'm lost on this one. When I change the tag I'm calling to  it does post so it's working, but in IE the design is all broken and the next links I click on don't post. Really strange!! Works fine in firefox, opera, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised IE complains about it, but it's a good thing it does: You're missing a declaration in `getPage` for `hash` (e.g., put `var` in front of the first use).

On the others it's presumably creating an implicit global (a property of the `window` object called `hash`), which is of course a [Bad Thing](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)(tm), but as I understand it it's correct according to the specification (the relevant sections being 8.7 ["The Reference
Type"] and 10.1.4 ["Scope Chain and Identifier Resolution"]).

Still surprised IE is complaining about it, though. It must have to do with the scope in which jQuery is calling your click handler.

Comment: ive narrowed it down to the tbody tag. Any idea why this is causing a problem? Does IE not recognise this tag? PS Thx you were right about the things you mentioned as well

Comment: @Ke: IE recognises the `tbody` tag, yes. I've just realized that you were doing `$('tbody').html(html)` -- do your *really* want to write this content to every `tbody` on the page? And what's the HTML you're writing to it? Persumably a series of `tr` elements... IE doesn't much like you mucking about with table rows via `innerHTML`, but I assume jQuery is handling that for you (Prototype does and I don't think jQuery is more backward in that area, but I don't know jQuery well).

Answer (score 6):

IF you get this error when using HTML5 elements in IE, make sure you're using html5shim to tell IE that these are real elements.

Comment: [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) can also be used, as it contains [html5shim](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/).

Answer (score 4):

It will be the:

```
$('tbody').html(html);
```

IE throws an error when you try to put certain things inside some nodes. Eg

```
$('<input>').append('</p>')
```

To fix this, add the `html` to a different element. For example, you could try:

```
$('table').html('<tbody>' + html + '</tbody>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a history method in the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) so I presume it's either:

- A third-party plugin.
- An indirect call to good old [window.history](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535864%28VS.85%29.aspx) object.
- A custom object you created.

My guess is that IE (well known for polluting the global scope by making everything global) thinks any reference to **history** actually means **window.history** and it's getting confused. If it's a custom object, try to rename it into **myHistory** or anything else.

Comment: i did all this and this history plugin seems somewhat broken. also has problems with more than 50 chars in url, think i will have to find another way, cheers anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that Mr. Crowder is on to something. As far as I can tell from the jQuery source, if your returned HTML fragment doesn't contain any `<script>` tags, and doesn't have a couple of other not-too-likely characteristics, then jQuery is probably trying to stuff it into your `<tbody>` element by using the "innerHTML" property. IE doesn't like that.

What you might have to do is wrap the whole `<table>` in a dummy `<div>` and then rebuild the entire thing from your HTML fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in a web application that used HTML5 elements. When I included the Modernizr script into the pages, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Originally there was a select list that was getting an  appended to it.  Along the way the select was changed to an input field.  Trying to append an option tag to an input field seem to make IE unhappy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem right now. It seems to me that it happens for non-visible elements. Verify if  your element is visible at the moment of calling `.html()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting any input fields?

I had the same issue, looping through an array of values, but I had changed a text box to an input. Chrome just ignores it, but IE 8 blows up.

`$("#someID").html("someValue")` = boom! on IE 8 if someID is an input

Already had the val call, but needed to remove the html one.

`$("#someID").val("someValue")` = good