# Jquery bbq php implementation

Tags: jquery, plugins

I just finished implementing the history plugin for URL back button functionality and now find out that it doesnt work with IE (great!?#) I wrote this post to explain the problems i was having [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350554/javascript-ie-error-unexpected-call-to-method-or-property-access)

So, next up is to try and implement the BBQ jquery plugin which does the same thing, but I cannot find any simple examples of how to implement this in PHP. Here is the history plugin example i was following, its v simple [history plugin example](http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp)

The history plugin is shown in my last post and I would like to do the same thing for bbq, but the examples of bbq given are just basic html and incredibly difficult to adapt to the history method ie using $_POST to get the different page fragments.

If anyone has any ideas on how I might get started on this, experience to share, or has any v simple tutorials I would really appreciate the help.

Cheers Ke

Comment: seems as though there are some better examples in the comments section of the bbq plugin website, so will start implementing them. Seems IE tho still have problems even with this plugin. How annoying! MS we luv u ... NOT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [implementation for the Kohana PHP framework](http://www.ygamretuta.com/2011/01/implementing-jquery-bbq-in-kohana-v3-ko3/).