# Unexpected call to method or property access in IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

For work, I need to get our site working in IE7.  Because, as we all know, the corporate world can't upgrade.

I am using IE8's IE7 emulation mode to test the site, and using IE8's wonderful debugger has been a nightmare.

My most recent problem is the following error:

```
Unexpected call to method or property access.  jquery.js, line 113 character 460
```

I've put `console.log` commands on every line of my function, and figured out the line that's causing the error.

```
var $loading = $('<span/>').addClass('span-icon icon-ajax-loader').html('Loading...');
```

This line works fine in Firefox and Chrome.  Oh, and it works fine when entering it into IE8's JavaScript console.

Why would this line give `Unexpected call to method or property access`?  I think the call to the method or property was totally expected.

UPDATE: As per @Pointy's suggestion I broke that line into 3 lines.

```
var $loading = $('<span/>');
$loading.addClass('span-icon icon-ajax-loader');
$loading.html('Loading...');
```

Now I'm getting the error on this call `$loading.html('Loading...');`.  Again, if I paste this code into IE8's developer tools and run it, it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried taking apart that jQuery chain and running each function individually?

Comment: Also: what version of jQuery is involved here?

Comment: @Pointy: jQuery 1.4.4, and no I have not tried that.

Comment: Hmm ... I wonder if maybe it doesn't like setting "innerHTML" when the element isn't part of the DOM yet?  Seems pretty weird to me.  Unfortunately I don't have access to IE at the moment (well, I guess that's not so unfortunate :-)

Comment: try changing <span /> to <span></span>. i remember IE has a few bugs regarding that

Comment: @Pointy: Then why does it work if I paste the code into the JavaScript console?

Comment: I agree; it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky: WTF?  That worked!  Why did that work?  Why did entering the original code into the JavaScript console work?

Comment: @Pointy: Neither does IE in the first place.

Comment: Hmm - that's quite strange - jQuery (I *think*) has code to transform self-closing tags, so somehow that must have not done it's thing. (Or maybe I'm thinking of code elsewhere in the library.)

Comment: @Pointy...did not realize you were suppose to append to the DOM before writing to the .innerHTML..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you injecting the content? Have you looked at this question and answer?
[Javascript IE error: unexpected call to method or property access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350554/javascript-ie-error-unexpected-call-to-method-or-property-access/4184464#4184464)

Comment: I'm trying to create a new span with the classes 'span-icon' and 'icon-ajax-loader', and with the innerHTML 'Loading...'.

Comment: That question you linked to helped.  `.html('<span>Loading...</span>')` worked, but `.html('Loading...')` did not.  Oh, and yeah the jsFiddle worked in IE too.   WTF IE?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @daniellmb and @yoavmatchulsky for helping me fix this issue.

There are actually 3 separate solutions.

Use `.text()` instead of `.html()`.

```
var $loading = $('<span/>').addClass('span-icon icon-ajax-loader').text('Loading...');
```

Wrap the `.html()` in span tags.

```
var $loading = $('<span/>').addClass('span-icon icon-ajax-loader').html('<span>Loading...</span>');
```

Or replace `$('<span/>')` with `$('<span></span>')`.

```
var $loading = $('<span></span>').addClass('span-icon icon-ajax-loader').html('Loading...');
```