# IE8/9 does not run JavaScript but IE8/9 Debugger does

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I see no evidence that IE8 is running my JavaScript.

However when I go to debug it using the f12 tools, it runs my javascript when the Debugger handles the reload.

However if I do the reload from the user's point of view (hitting reload), I once again see the javascript is not running.

It is clear that an debug assisted reload is different from a user reload. ( The debugger requests to do the reload )

Why the difference...what can I do?

There are no error messages.  I don't plan to support IE8 but I need this code to run in order to identify it and report to the user.

Comment: Do you have `console.log`s in your code?  IE8 is stupid, and `console` doesn't exist unless the dev tools are open.

Comment: an old fashioned alert? Just to verify it's running?

Comment: Can you post what code isn't running?

Comment: @Rocket I know.  I do a document.body.appendChildElement() to get an output to the user that does not render in the browser....however when the debugger runs the code and displays it fine.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist: I had a similar issue (http://stackoverflow.com/q/5637893/206403).  The code ran great in the debugger, but not normally.

Comment: One thing I noted is that IE8 when in full screen mode and when you cursor to the top of the Full Screen to get the Menu to drop down...is that IE does not render the page correctly...an obvious bug...just noticed this and I'm not too sure how much that thew me off in my debugging as if my message was there I might not have seen it.

Comment: Another thing to consider per a comment by Pointy in Rocket's post is wether you append the DOM or do the .innerHTML write first when dynamically loading JavaScript....Lots of variables...but my temp fix was to remove log.console and just do a document.write() to eliminate  possible problems...this works.

Comment: Ended up replacing a child append with a document.write and wrapping console.log w/ a check..works now....but b.c. I changed two things at once..I don't know which one fixed the issue....Going to put the child append back in...and if all still works I'll have narrowed it down.

Comment: Put back the append child and it still works...pretty sure console.log causes a silent fail....will put it back in to verify...and from there I'm reporting it as a bug...it needs to say something like console is undefined before exiting out of .js with no errors...feels good to be working on producing the bug instead of trying to fix broken code...

Comment: And...finally...I verified that putting the console.log back in breaks the code........this is a bug ( though not technically ) ...b.c. it is a Catch-22...if you turn the debugger on you fix the issue....but if you don't it breaks...if not for SO...I would not have a way to know it fails....or I would have to read up on IE's documentation for explanation of why it implements this different from Safari, Firefox and Chrome...or the "good browsers"

Comment: @Rocket - Thanks for setting my debugging on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have an ieshiv then you may want to consider. http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/ . I also agree with @Rocket 's assessment, make sure there are no console.log statements.

Comment: What does that shiv do for me...a link perhaps..I've never used a shiv before?

Comment: Shiv is a javascript application (may also be called shim) that basically makes up for missing features in a browser and therefore making it do essentially the same thing as newer versions of browsers.

Comment: I don't plan to support IE8 so I don't need a shim...I just want to report to the user it is not supported...and in time celebrate its non-existence.

Comment: Lucky you, i wish I had the liberty

Comment: I'm sorry...one day it will be gone for everyone.