# JavaScript Error:Unexpected Call To Method Or Property Access

Tags: java, javascript, dojo

Getting error while calling function

Comment: A tip: If you indent your code properly more people will help.

Comment: You should check out [David Crockford's javascript style guide](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html).

Comment: I hope it will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350554/javascript-ie-error-unexpected-call-to-method-or-property-access

Comment: Thanks Sean, eleclanrs and Korvin for guiding me regarding indentation of code...

Comment: @ swemon : Yes.. i had read that post which was related to Jquery where similar error was popping out but did not help with my situation. So i posted my question then.

Answer (score 0):

May be since you are using Ajax call, check whether your Ajax implementation API how to handle for IE as well. They way to call Ajax request is totally different in IE.

Answer (score 0):

My brain may be melting...

It's been a long couple of weeks, but in your `newEntry` string, you've got a comma at the end.

If you're doing anything to turn that set of strings into an object, anywhere inside of this program, and the last entry there has a trailing comma, then your program will likely die in old-IE.

Aside from that, make sure you're handling the "MSXML2.XMLHTTP" ActiveXObject in IE.

Comment: @ Nortguard :- I tried what you said. But Still i am facing this issue. Actually My Functionality goes like I want to save my data and after which i need to refresh my page with the new elements of data that got saved. So In My Functionality there are two Ajax Hits. After an ajaxhit for save i am having one ajaxhit for search too in the same function. If I am removing the search part "My functionality is working fine with no java script errors."..But i want the search too too along with my save functionality..:(