# .append issue with IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

This snipped code:

```
    var trackEvent = (function(event) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        $(script).html( event );
        $('head').append($(script));
    });
```

is not working in IE8 (JQuery version is 1.9). It just adds a new `script` tag to `<head>` with some content. I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350554/javascript-ie-error-unexpected-call-to-method-or-property-access/#answer-4184464) that it's probably an `append` issue, but how to solve it in this case?

**EDIT**:

My solution is to execute directly the code, instead of embedding it. Anyway, the issue with `.append` and IE8 still exists and this question may be useful for other users.

Comment: Why do you want to be appending a new script tag? What is in the event variable? Is it code you want to run?

Comment: Where are you getting the content of `event` from?

Comment: @RoToRa - When calling the `trackEvent` function (`trackEvent(event)`), where `event` is an executable code.

Comment: That's not what I asked. I asked, where are you getting it from?

Comment: @RoToRa - I'm manually assigning it.

Comment: But you must be getting it from somewhere. Or does it magically appear from nowhere?

Comment: @RoToRa - `event` is defined in different ways when calling the `trackEvent` function. I'm not sure if I understand you.

Comment: I'll try to ask this in a different way: Why do you have executable code in a string?

Comment: @RoToRa - Look at the updated question.

Comment: I don't see how that answers my question. I give up.

Comment: @RoToRa - The thing is why `.append` is not working on IE8 while it does on other browsers.

Comment: The thing is that you are looking at a far too small problem, instead of the big picture. IMHO you are shooting yourself in the foot, and insisting of fixing the foot, instead of telling me why you are shooting yourself in the foot in the first place, so I can tell you how to stop doing that.

Comment: @RoToRa - As you can see, the problem is solved for me. But I think that a generic answer could help someone struggled.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have IE8 (only IE11) I cannot reproduce the issue. But I can see that maybe older versions might not execute the inserted scripts automatically.
You could try the following workaround:

```
var trackEvent = (function(event) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');

    // Wrap code in a function
    var wrappedEvent = 'function __myTest() { ' + event + '}';
    $(script).html(wrappedEvent);
    $('head').append($(script));

    // Call that function
    __myTest();
});
```

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnsu5/1/) for you to try.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing vanilla js and jquery when you could just be using jquery. I don't think the two are playing nicely together here.

Try this jquery solution

```
var trackEvent = (function(event) {
  var script = $('<script>');
  script.attr('type','text/javascript');
  script.html(event);
  $('head').append(script);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The issue is with `.append` method.

Comment: Ah ok I see, I did a little googling and saw that it is an issue in ie7 and ie8. Sorry, can't help! Although if you let me know what the purpose of adding a script tag to the head is, then maybe you can find a different solution?